# How to use XmlnsDefinition in VB.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a solution with two projects: a WPF sample application called "WPFSample" and a class library project called "ReferencedAssembly". "WPFSample" references "ReferencedAssembly".

The project "ReferencedAssembly" contains a couple of classes. Every class has its own namespace, i.e. "MyClassLibrary" or "MyClassLibrary.MyOtherTypes". A sample class with the namespace "MyClassLibrary" is called "Movie".

Now I want to map the .NET namespace to the XAML namespace using the URL "http://schemas.emmbee.de/". For this purpose I added the following lines to AssemblyInfo.vb in the "WPFSample" project and build it afterwards:

```
Imports System.Windows.Markup

<Assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.emmbee.de/", "ra")>
<Assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.emmbee.de/",   "ReferencedAssembly.MyClassLibrary")>
<Assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.emmbee.de/", "ReferencedAssembly.MyClassLibrary.MyOtherTypes")>
```

In XAML I add the namespace definition like this:

```
<xmlns:ra="http://schemas.emmbee.de">
```

If I want to use the "Movie" class with

```
<ra:Movie/>
```

I receive the error, that the class "Movie" doesn't exists in namespace "http://schemas.emmbee.de".

If I instead add a namespace definition in this way:

```
<xmlns:ra="clr-namespace:ReferencedAssembly.MyClassLibrary;assembly=ReferencedAssembly">
```

all works fine.

What is wrong with the XmlnsDefinition?

Answer (score 0):

I found it out.The Namespace mappings

```
Imports System.Windows.Markup
<Assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.emmbee.de/", "ra")>
<Assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.emmbee.de/", "ReferencedAssembly.MyClassLibrary")>
<Assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.emmbee.de/", "ReferencedAssembly.MyClassLibrary.MyOtherTypes")>
```

must be included in the "AssemblyInfo.vb" in the assembly "ReferencedAssembly", not in the assembly "WPFSample".